# I am getting a nullpointerexception please help :)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So my problem is simply i get a `Nullpointerexception` when testing to create the array and cant figure out why :(
It wants more text so what i am doing is trying to make a deck of cards as u can probably see. I am using JUnit to test the creation of the array but i am getting failure.

Exception is at the If statement.

```
public class Deck {

private int type;
private int text; 

private String[] texts;
private String[] types;
private CardMaster[] deck = new CardMaster[38];

public CardMaster[] getDeck() {
    return deck;
}


public void setDeck(CardMaster[] deck) {
    this.deck = deck;
}


public Deck() 
{
    for(int i = 0;i<deck.length;i++)
    {
        int id;

        Random Rgen = new Random();     

        id = Rgen.nextInt(deck.length+1);

        do
        {
            if (deck[id].equals(null))
            {
                deck[id] = new CardMaster("test");
            }
        }   
        while(!deck[id].equals(null));

    }
}
```

Comment: On which line? where is your stacktrace?

Comment: Something needs to be initialized there.. `deck[id]` wasn't initialized.. the default values are `null`.

Comment: Could you please change the title ?

Comment: Do you know what a NullPointereException is? Did you Google it? Did you read your error message? Did you look at your code where your error message says to?

Comment: I am very new to programming so sorry if i have sounded like an imbecile :) I have read on NPE and checked the error message but did not realise equals is only used to compare objects.

What do you want me to change the title to then? It did say it was an NPE so what is wrong with Title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
do{
     if (deck[id] == null){
         deck[id] = new CardMaster("test");
     }
}   
while(deck[id] != null);
```

Basically: .equals() is used to compare objects. Use == to compare to null.

Answer (score 4):

change this line         `while(!deck[id].equals(null));` to         `while(deck[id]!=null);`

Also
change this `if (deck[id].equals(null))` to `if (deck[id]==null)`

Comment: I chose the other comment as answer because i think it was the first to arrive. Both your answers do fix my problem tho, so i would also like to thank you for your effort.
It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @user3172787 you are welcome.I was busy in answering other questions and I think Niko's answer is better than mine.If you have any other questions then feel free to ask.Always ready to help

Answer (score 1):

In the statement "deck[i].equals(null)" you are actually calling equals() method on a null reference.
Change the check as suggested in the above answers.

Answer (score 1):

**equals()** method is used for comparing actual values(that are being referenced by object reference variables ) not references.
And because you are comparing a refererence variable and null **{deck[i].equals(null)}** You are getting NPE.
[See here for equals method Details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 0):

equals is used for comparing two objects and null is not an instance of any class therefore you have to replace equals with == or !=.